# Execute command in ubuntu terminal from an aspnet application

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I have a command to drop postgresql database:

```
sudo -u myuser psql -c "drop database my_databse"
```

How I could execute this sentence from an aspnet website(c#)?
Is it possible to execute without introducing a password?

This app is running in another server:
I have a windows server running aspnet website.
I have an ubuntu server running postgresql database.

Comment: this might help : http://codeabout.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/working-with-postgres-database-and-c-by-using-npgsql-and-reflection/

Comment: I am using npgsql, but I want directly drop the databse from command in the server. THanks

Answer (score 1):

`drop database my_databse` is an SQL command. You can run it directly from nPgSQL. There is no need to run `psql`, and no point doing so.

If your usual user account doesn't have the access rights for it, you can make a new temporary connection in nPgSQL just for that command. You might find `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` or `SET ROLE` useful, too.

Comment: But, it is giving me problems: It is giving me some errors: there are open connections

Comment: I tried it too, but If I do this, It disconnect me.

Comment: Did you add an exception for your own connection? If not, then yes, it'll disconnect you.

Comment: Yes, I have exception added

Comment: I think you'll need to show the query then, because it should work, and always has in the past...